# conversion rates on payment page with our without header and footer

Tags: conversion, payment, conversion-rate

I have an e-com site, and when the visitor gets to the payment page, I show the standard template of header and footer. I was wondering is it better to remove them both, as to not distract the visitor, offering them other places to go, rather than complete the payment form?

Answer (score 2):

yes, the footer. or at least a lot of the seo content on it can be removed after cart and thru ought the checkout. The header should be minimised or removed as well to avoid the user from getting distracted and navigating away from the checkout process.